# Codesmith 6.x unable to resolve assembly

Tags: codesmith

I am fairly new using codesmith. I've done couple of editings here and there but right now I have to make fairly big changes to our template

My question is, I am trying to add an assembly to our new template, specifically Oracle.DataAccess.Client. Below is how I added it in my CST file but I am still receiving unable to resolve assembly error.

```
<%@ Assembly Name="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

To resolve an assembly please see this [documentation](http://docs.codesmithtools.com/display/Generator/Referencing+Assemblies). It details where the assembly must be located and/or how to specify where to load the assembly from.

Answer (score 2):

The line should look like this

```
<%@ Assembly Name="HtmlAgilityPack" path="G:\myproject\bin\Debug" %>
```

I find that sometimes you have to restart Generator for the reference to take. 
Sometimes just REBUILDING the template works. 
I dont have a good answer as to why.

you can also paste the DLLs here

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeSmith\v7.1\bin
```

but this is problematic if you are using a DLL that is under development as you have to keep copying the file out.

Note , this is on v7 and the question references v6. 
I have been using CS for years, I dont think this question is version specific, so I am posting on this question rather than creating another one. 
Rather than downvote me, please make a comment and I will create a new question. Its sixes, doesnt really matter in my opinion.